# passing headers into file_get_contents() for a json request

Tags: php, json, http-headers, httpwebrequest, file-get-contents

I need to pass these headers into the `$context` variable, i tried using putting the values into an array and then passing it into `stream_context_create()` function but i get http warnings from the `file_getcontents` function

```
$prod_id = 4322;
$tnxRef = "RT45635276GHF76783AC";
$mackey =  "ADECNH576748GH638NHJ7393MKDSFE73903673";
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$hash = hash('SHA512', $prod_id.$txnRef.$mackey);

$headers = array(
    'http'=>(
        'method'=>'GET',
        'header'=>'Content: type=application/json \r\n'.
            '$agent \r\n'.
            '$hash'
        )
    )
stream_context_create($headers)

$url_returns = file_get_contents("https://test_server.com/test_paydirect/api/v1/gettransaction.json?productid=$prod_id&transactionreference=$txnRef&amount=$amount", false, $context);  

$json = json_decode($url_returns, true);
```

**Error:**

> [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

Thats the error i get, can somebody please help with a definitive example.

Comment: OPS, [the main  source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497253/passing-headers-into-file-get-contents) not there!

Comment: Page not found on the duplicate links...

Answer (score 4):

You have several errors in your code.

The server returns `400 Bad Request`, because your code would result in this incorrect HTTP request:

```
GET /test_paydirect/api/v1/gettransaction.json?productid=4322&transactionreference=RT45635276GHF76783AC&amount= HTTP/1.1
Host: test_server.com
Content: type=application/json
$agent
$hash
```

The errors are:

1. Variable expressions are not evaluated within single quotes
2. `$amount` is not set in your code example
3. The header is `Content-Type:` and not `Content: type=`
4. All headers (agent, hash) must have their corresponding name

Here is an example that *should* work:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'agent'  => $agent,
    'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
        . "X-Api-Signature: $hash"
    )
  )
);
```

**Please note:** `X-Api-Signature` is just an example - it depends on the API you are using how the API key header is named and how the hash is calculated. You should find this information in the Docs of your API!

Comment: thanks for the response,this is what i have now      $options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'header'=>"Content-Type: application/json",
    'UserAgent'=>$agent,
    'Hash'=>$hash
  
  )
) but still does not get the right response

Comment: this what they want to get https://test_server.com/test_paydirect/api/v1/gettransaction.json?productid=$prod_id&transactionreference=$txnRef&amount=$amount HTTP/1.1 UserAgent: Mozilla/blah blah blah(blah) Hash: myhash

Comment: @user1872101: 1. the headers name is `User-Agent`. Also, there is a seperate stream context option for this, which i used in my example. Just use it like it is! 2. I'm sure it is because of your `Hash` header. Go read the docs of your API or post them here so people are able to really help you.

Comment: and the $amount is pass from a session, so it is covered